# Newly compiled kernel not booting up (vanilla kernel 3.12.14)

Tags: boot, kernel, virtualbox

[image: Boot-up Error Screen]

I downloaded, configured and installed kernel downloaded from kernel.org. While booting up this new kernel for the first time, this error screen shows which is pointing towards a missing or wrongly mentioned root device probably. But I didn't mention it explicitly, installation scripts did it. So if this is the error, can someone please tell how to fix?

Or if the cause may be something else, please tell what it can be?

NOTE: I am using VirtualBox for all this process. Don't want my laptop to become unbootable for this experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!!
It was the drivers for my hard disk controller, SATA AHCI was not added while configuring kernel before compilation. Now I added, recompiled and viola! new installed kernel booted up. :)